# Why is Jquery prepending img src with window url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this simple code:

```
var openPopUp = function(_type, _src) {
    $(_type).bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#img_pop_up').bPopup({
            onOpen: function() {
                console.log(document.getElementById("jpg_pop_up")['src']);
                $("#jpg_pop_up").attr("src",_src);
                /*$("#jpg_pop_up").attr("src","http://freefever.com/stock/2013-abstract-hd-wallpaper.jpg");*/
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The line mentioned in the comment works just fine but when I pass a variable as _src it prepends the src with window.location url and then tries to get the image. Its like http://myserver.com/http://image_url/ Any idea why is that? I am passing the absolute url. When I do console.log(_src) it prints the complete url fine but when I print

```
console.log(document.getElementById("jpg_pop_up")['src']);
```

this prints my window location url! It is supposed to be null.

When I hardcode the path of the url it works fine but when I pass the path with a variable then it assumes that as a relative path.

Comment: you could do a substring of the src

Comment: are you sure to not set `<base href="">` inside your hmtl? -> example http://jsfiddle.net/vCJef/

Comment: @Frogmouth No there is no base href set. Can it because its using a bpopup jquery which pops a different model for the mentioned div and some scope changes?

Comment: And how does all that have anything to do with angularjs?

Comment: @Stewie Since My trigger for the function was coming from angular js partials so I thought if that is related somewhere.

Comment: Then you put your code in some angular context if you think angular might have something to do with it. Otherwise it's a pure jQuery/JS question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('jpg_pop_up').getAttribute("src"));
```

The important difference here is that the `src` *attribute* contains what you gave it, but the `src` *property* contains the fully-resolved URL.

Comment: So console.log(document.getElementById('jpg_pop_up').getAttribute("src")); prints null as expected but using the same way I tried to set the value as document.getElementById('jpg_pop_up').setAttribute("src",_src) but its again prepending with http://localhost:.../http://img_url/